# Extract json data with double quotes in Karate BDD

Tags: karate

How do I extract auth token from the below json response payload to use in the subsequent request (seems like I am having trouble as the key in the key value has double quotes)?

> Feature: `test oauth`
>      Background:
>       * url `https://xxx.yyy.com`
>      Scenario: `Get xxx-subject`
>       Given path `xxx/oauth/internal/proof/srvc`
>       And headers `someData`
>       When method `get`
>       Then status `200`
>       And print `'authorization :'$[2]`

Response Payload:

```
{
    "xxx-gateway-proof":"xxxx",
    "xxx-subject":" yyy",
    "authorization":"Bearer zzz"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not to double quotes, it is the hyphen `-` sign that causes problems in JSON keys as it is interpreted as a minus sign.

I just tested the below, it works:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "xxx-gateway-proof": "xxxx",
  "xxx-subject":" yyy",
  "authorization": "Bearer zzz"
}
"""
* def proof = response['xxx-gateway-proof']
* match proof == 'xxxx'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. Earlier, i was trying def proof = response.'xxx-gateway-proof'